# Retrieve IP addresses with PHP's gethostbyname()

Tags: php

Using the code below I've been able to open a `.csv` file with several domain names, which I then put in a PHP array and loop through. In the loop I call a function that returns the IP address of each domain (`gethostbyname()`).

However, when I execute this, I simply get the domain names echoed back to me. When I use this function on a single domain (i.e. not in a loop) I get the IP address as desired.

What's going wrong here? Is there some sort of in built limit or am I building the array wrong?

```
<?php

$urls = file('test.csv'); 

foreach($urls as $url){

    $ip = gethostbyname($url);
    echo $ip.'<br/>';
}

?>
```

Comment: You'll need to post an example of what's in the CSV file.

Comment: `gethostbyname` returns the hostname, unmodified, upon failure. What IP host are you trying to look up?

Answer (score 1):

`file()` returns the contents of the file as an array, but also includes the linebreak characters at the end of the lines, so most likely you're trying to do a lookup on something like `google.com\n`. Try using

```
$urls = file('test.csv', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

or

```
foreach($urls as $url) {
   $ip = gethostbyname(trim($url)); // note the use of trim()
}
```